# CMake: Install files not yet created at configuration time

Tags: python, cmake, protocol-buffers

I do have a project with a Protobuf interface that I need to compile and install for Python using CMake.

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like below:

```
file(GLOB PROTO_INPUT "*.proto")
add_custom_target(BuildPythonInterface ALL
  protoc -I=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} --python_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${PROTO_INPUT}
  DEPENDS ${PROTO_INPUT})
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*_pb2.py")
LIST(APPEND PROTOBUF_INTERFACE "${INIT_PY}" )
install(FILES ${PROTOBUF_INTERFACE} DESTINATION "lib/python2.7/site-packages/${PROJECT_NAME}/proto/")
```

It does indeed work like a charm, when running it twice, but if I delete my build directory and start configering it from the scratch, then the protobuf-interface files for Python are not being found by `file(GLOB PROTOBUF_INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*_pb2.py")` as they are not yet existent, until the `make all` command is run once.

Is there a way to make CMake execute the above code line after having run the build once? 
Or maybe an other (cleaner?) way of doing this?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why using globs for source and output files is discouraged in CMake. You should list the inputs and outputs explicitly, then it will work just fine.

Comment: @Angew Yeah, I agree that this could be a solution, but I might add or remove Protobuf files and I have a ton of them. That's why I would prefer a generic solution over explicitly adding all names in the CMakeLists.

Comment: Well, but if you add some, you'll have to remember to re-run CMake manually, because of course the `GLOB` will not pick up stuff you add when it's not re-evaluated. That's why CMake *strongly discourages* globbing for source files. You can put the list into a separate file and `include()` that to keep your CMakeList tidy, if you prefer.

Comment: @Angew as what I am doing is part of a project that is being configured, built and installed from the scratch every time that does really not cause any problems to me. But the problem here is that the `file(GLOB ...)` does not catch any file, as for the first configuration before anything is built there are no files ending with `_pb2.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred CMake way of doing this would be to list both input and output files explicitly instead of using `file(GLOB)`. There are multiple reasons for this; what you're facing is one of them; the fact that with `GLOB`, adding a file does not cause an automatic re-run of CMake (and thus the file is not picked up) is another.

Nevertheless, if `GLOB`s are the best way to go in your specific scenario (as you mentioned in comments), you can solve this by using `install(DIRECTORY)` instead of installing files. Something like this:

```
file(GLOB PROTO_INPUT "*.proto")

add_custom_target(BuildPythonInterface ALL
  protoc -I=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} --python_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ToBeInstalled ${PROTO_INPUT}
  DEPENDS ${PROTO_INPUT})

install(
  DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ToBeInstalled/
  DESTINATION "lib/python2.7/site-packages/${PROJECT_NAME}/proto/"
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*_pb2.py"
)

install(FILES ${INIT_PY} DESTINATION "lib/python2.7/site-packages/${PROJECT_NAME}/proto/")
```

Notice the trailing slash in the `DIRECTORY` argument. It's important: if it wasn't present, the name `ToBeInstalled` would be appended to the destination directory. With the trailing slash, this appending is suppressed.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm, did just have to exclude a directory I didn't want to get installed along.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but not with install; I generate source files with custom command at build time and GLOB these files using regular expression(tons of source files, it's impossible to explicitly list all of them), does anybody have a clue how to do this?